# customize default menu styling for web.sitemap using css

Tags: asp.net, css

I am using `web.sitemap` to display the menu for the asp.net application, which is looking fine, but by default the submenus for the main menu items will be displayed vertically like below. 
[image]

But I want to display submenu as **horizontally**. I am trying to change with css. But it is not changing. The main class for the div is `mainmenu`. To customize this i am using css like below.

```
.mainmenu ul li ul li{
position:relative;
float:left;
}
```

But it is not going to the left. I given `display:inline`, even though it is not working. Can't we customize the menu which is coming from `web.sitemap` provider or am I doing any wrong here?
Here the [JS Fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/y2GjA/)

Comment: can you post the related HTML and CSS or even better a jsfiddle?

Comment: i am using asp.net web.sitemap provider. so it doesn't have any html. .net runtime will render the menu dynamically. So I am not able to post the html which I don't know. :)

Comment: You mean that your browser displays a page and you can't "view source" of that page or there's no html/css generated?

Comment: not like that... after rendering to the page we can see the html. You want that html?

Comment: of course... and the generated css please

Comment: I pased the html and all the .css files code. But the submenu is not coming. I think it is because of asp.net (don't have idea). See the jsfiddle link in edited post

Comment: BTW the submenu has an inline style of `display:none`. It's there but not visible.

Answer (score 1):

There are many inline styles to your html that override your css classes and ids. I managed to find a quick fix for  displaying your level2 `li` items horizontally but this is only temporary since I need to find out what's causing the level2 `ul` not to align to the left of the menu. Place this in your css file:

```
li.dynamic{
    display:table-cell;
}
```

And here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/y2GjA/1/

I will see what I can do for a better solution since this is only a temp solution and not compatible with IE8 and older.

**--EDIT--**

Add the following to your CSS:

```
li.static:nth-child(6):hover ul.level2{
    left:-481px!important;
}
li.dynamic {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

And here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uSmSD/

Comment: This one is great yaar. Firs time i am hearing about dipslay:table-cell.

Comment: Just one question: Can you edit inline styles or you only have control to external stylesheet?

Comment: That is rendered output. i dont have any inline stylesheets. I have external style sheet only. Those inline styles are rendered by asp.net